# How to modify string inside CSV for current PowerShell Session

Tags: powershell

I need to import a csv, select a string and change some part of it's value to `$env:username`. I think I have to work with `select-string` to get the string, but i'm stuck with changing the value. Or is it possible to write `$env:username` directly into the csv? I wasn't able to do it. also, the CSV should stay the way it is, only the current powershell session needs the correct string

CSV looks like this, `userhome` should be replaced by `$env:username`:

```
Test        Test2
-----       -----
Hi          C:\user\userhome
something   C:\test\install
hello       C:\windows
```

Thats what i tried but I'm not successfull.

```
$test.Test2 | sls userhome -replace ($env:username)
```

another approach:

```
sls ($test.Test2).value -replace ("userhome",$env:username)
```

**EDIT:** This is the whole command where this csv is needed - just for information:

```
$Drives = Import-CSV .\NetworkDrives.csv -Delimiter ';' | ? {(($_.Group).split(',') -contains $UserOU) -and (!(Test-Path $_.Letter))} | % { #Do Stuff }
```

Comment: `$Csv | % {$_.PSObject.Properties} | % {$_.Value = $_.Value -replace "userhome", $env:username}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that PetSerAl's answer in the comments worked for you. Personally I think it may have been simpler to use `Get-Content`, run a `-Replace` on that, and then pipe to `ConvertFrom-CSV` instead of `Import-CSV`.

```
$Drives= (Get-Content .\NetworkDrives.csv) -Replace "userhome",$env:username | ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter ';' | ? {(($_.Group).split(',') -contains $UserOU) -and (!(Test-Path $_.Letter))} | % { #Do Stuff }
```

Comment: thank you MadTechnician. I will test this asap, see which solution works faster and then accept your answer. Funny thing: you gave me 2 months ago an answer to a question which was for the same script. so you will be listed as co-autor ;-). cheers!